# Do graduate schools check the disciplinary record of PhD applicants?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, disciplinary-action

Do Physics (STEM) graduate schools in the US check for disciplinary record if they don't ask for it in the application? The outcome of the violation doesn't appear on my transcript. Only way a graduate school can find out is if they ask my school (in US) for my academic record. I am not going to lie if they ask but some school's application form doesn't ask for disciplinary records. Does that mean they will not check for it?

Comment: This will surely depend on the school.. many schools also don't have the concept of a "disciplinary record"..

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing where the information is available.  It would depend on the country and sometimes on the preferences of individuals.  In any case, do not lie about your record on your application.

Comment: Is this a question about the US or elsewhere? Laws differ.

Comment: @Buffy it's for US

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Could you let me know what more I should include?

Comment: @user111388 what kind of school are those?

Comment: @user131275: many (most?) schools in Europe (minus UK).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.

Answer (score 2):

[In the US disciplinary records are protected by FERPA, so one school can't check another's records without written permission from the applicant](https://nces.ed.gov/pubs97/web/97859.asp). Others here that say that the school you are applying to is free to ask you about why your transcript looks the way it does, are right. If you got kicked out of a school or failed a class for cheating, expect your transcript to reflect that somehow that's legal and to be asked about that in another way that's legal.

Comment: But the outcome of the violation is not on my transcript, does that mean they can not ask for it without my permission?

Comment: @user131275 how would they know about it if it’s not on your official transcript or other documents sent by the university where it was committed? FERPA prevents that university from telling without your written permission.

Comment: It is not on my transcript but it is on my educational/academic record

Comment: @user131275 that’s definitely not something that one school can get from another. Some schools won’t even let you buy your own official transcript, just an unofficial copy. My uni only sends official transcripts to other unis for money.

Comment: FERPA has exceptions for the prior consent requirement such as disciplinary records (you can find it in the link in your post). My question is do schools ask for it?

Comment: @user131275, I think you're misreading the places that say 'prior' as they're mostly related to children, and, no, to my limited knowledge, graduate admissions committees don't go seeking the other records of applicants than they ask you to send or have sent like letters of rec. and transcripts. That would be too much to review.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in the US, you can depend to some extent on a "right to privacy" that would make such an inquiry improper and replying to it also improper. But it isn't necessarily assured.

The US Constitution is silent on a right to privacy, but many Supreme Court decisions have expanded that right, though not to the extent of the EU's Right to be Forgotten. Also, many US states will have privacy protections in place that make the communication of certain kinds of information improper without the consent of the person involved.

However, if some transgression of a student is also law-breaking, then the rules may change and the information may be part of the public record in that case.

In addition, most (I think) US colleges and universities would treat disciplinary action against a student as a private matter and some might purge the record upon graduation (or after some time period). Part of the philosophy is that if we are to punish a student for some act then that should be the end of it, though the record might be retained until graduation to guard against recurrences.

Overall, I doubt that, given the more or less general, if informal, sense that privacy is a right, that any graduate school would ask and that the likelihood of getting an answer would be very small.

Part of the reasoning here is that the grad school would have no particular reason to ask, having no evidence of any wrongdoing on the part of an applicant.

Of course, it is not outside the realm of possibility that the candidate would be asked directly about certain kinds of misbehavior, and if asked it would be a potential problem if a candidate were to lie (as noted by Anonymous Physicist).

Comment: Yes some applications asks if the applicant has been placed on 'probation/suspension or expelled' etc for a violation, and some don't. My question is those that don't pose this question on their application, would they ask my current school for disciplinary records?

Comment: It seems doubtful, as I said. Asking you is a different matter, of course. They can also ask you for a release for such information and then it is up to the university as to how to reply.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience some schools take a very hard line on academic dishonesty and expel students for cheating on exams. This would probably show up on your record.

Other schools give students a few strikes by having an internal list of disciplinary action, so that a repeat offender can be identified for expulsion. Otherwise the list stays private and probably won't come to light in future applications.

Discipline regarding drinking in dorms and things like that probably won't show up unless it gets so bad that you have a criminal record.